# How to pass a inner function within Python class

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to do a hyeropt parameter tuning using a class to incorporate different models and parameter grids. Here is my code:

```
class hopt:
  def __init__(self, clf, params, x, y):
    self.clf = clf
    self.params = params
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

  def f(self):
    self.clf = self.clf(**self.params, random_state=2019, n_jobs=-1)
    score = cross_val_score(self.clf, self.x, self.y, scoring='roc_auc', cv=StratifiedKFold(5, True, 2019))
    pred = cross_val_predict(self.clf, self.x, self.y, cv=StratifiedKFold(5, True, 2019),
                             method='predict_proba',
                             n_jobs=-1)[:, 1]
    return {'loss': -np.mean(score), 'status': STATUS_OK, 'pred': pred}

  def search(self, max_evals, f=f):
    trials = Trials()
    fmin(f, self.params, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=max_evals, rstate=np.random.RandomState(2019), trials=trials)
    return trials.best_trial['result']['pred'][:, 1]
```

What I'm trying to do is to pass function "f" to function "search", both of which are created within the class. But I got the error message:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'clf'

Sorry, I'm new to Python class. Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: You already have passed `self` which is the object itself. Get access to the function `f` like `self.f`. No need to pass it.

Comment: I assume OP wants to be able to change the function that is used in `search`

Comment: Please post `fmin()` definition - we need to know how it's using `f`.

Comment: Actually, post a proper MCVE () and the exact full traceback produced by the MCVE. Also this `self.clf = self.clf(**self.params, random_state=2019, n_jobs=-1)` is very certainly wrong - it tries to call `self.clf` (whatever it is - we don't know) then rebinds `self.clf` to the result value. Depending on what the missing code does, it might have something to do with your issue.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for the response. What fmin() tries to do is try different combinations in self.params (which is a dictionary) and run the function f() to achieve the lowest "loss" return by f(). Here is the website: https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt. CLF is a sklearn model (let's say I use RandomforestClassifier and I try to pass the params into it).